# Flutter shared preferences crash on iPhone 5 (Invalid radix-16 number)

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I get a "FormatException: Invalid radix-16 number" Only on my test device iPhone 5 (10.1.1). Using  shared_preferences: ^0.4.3 plugin. Works fine on all other devices and simulators.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this issue ? Thank you.

```
class _MyProfileHomePageState extends State<MyProfileHomePage> {

  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance(); //Line 44
  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  ProfileDataModel _profileDataModel;

  String _fullName;
  String _emailID;
  ...
  ..
  .

}
```

// ERROR LOG...

```
2018-10-24 17:43:18.552844 Runner[460:162775] [VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Invalid radix-16 number
ffffffffa20ecb9b
#0      int._throwFormatException (dart:core/runtime/libintegers_patch.dart:130:5)
#1      int._parse (dart:core/runtime/libintegers_patch.dart:104:14)
#2      int.parse (dart:core/runtime/libintegers_patch.dart:61:12)
#3      StandardMessageCodec.readValueOfType (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:396:22)
#4      StandardMessageCodec.readValue (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:365:12)
#5      StandardMessageCodec.readValueOfType (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:432:39)
#6      StandardMessageCodec.readValue (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:365:12)
#7      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:546:27)
#8      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:279:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      SharedPreferences.getInstance (package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart:24:62)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     new _MyProfileHomePageState (package:callpages/callpages_pages/MyProfileHomePage.dart:44:56)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21313). Please upvote it to increase priority.